# Unable to match <div> height

Tags: html, css

I have a parent  that is set to `height:0` and `padding-bottom:100%` in order to maintain a square aspect ratio. Within the parent, I would like to have another div that would take up 80% of the parent's height.

```
<div class="parent" style="width:100%; height:0; padding-bottom:100%">
   <div class="child" style="width:100%; height: 80%"></div>
</div>
```

I understand that the height of 80% is relative to its parent's and with the parent's height set to 0, it is only logical that the child's height would be affected. Is there any workaround in maintain both aspect ratio for the parent while keeping the ability to manipulate the child's height?

Comment: you need to make the element inside to be position:absolute ... even if the height works like you want you cannot put an element on the padding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can position the child absolutely:

```
<div class="parent" style="width:100%; height:0; padding-bottom:100%">
    <div class="child" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 10%; right: 0; bottom: 10%"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the vw unit:

```html
<div class="parent" style="width:100vw; height:100vw">
   <div class="child" style="width:100%; height: 80%"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried using viewport, but its relative to the entire screen. I would like to keep it within the "grandparent". Using 100vw would take up the entire screen.

Comment: Sorry then, I don't know any other solution.